# Small JavaScript animation integration

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function hideshow(which) {
    if (!document.getElementById)
      return
    if (which.style.display=="block")
      which.style.display="none"
    else
      which.style.display="block"
  }
</script>
```

how can I integrate a `.slideToggle(1000);` animation this code?

Comment: Can you please provide codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) can't be animated, what you can do is combining it with opacity in css.
default css:

```
display:none;
opacity:0;
transition:1s opacity ease;
-webkit-transition:1s opacity ease;
```

JS:

```
 which.style.display="block"
 which.style.opacity="1"
```

Since you are new to javascript i didn't provide complete solution but you should've get the idea.